# How long does it take for a $\rm CO_2$ molecule close to the surface of the Earth to reemit an absorbed terrestial infrared quant after absorption?

Tags: photons, atomic-physics, atmospheric-science, climate-science

In the theory of climate change a special position is reserved for $\rm CO_2$. In this theory $\rm CO_2$ molecules are absorbing infrared quants emitted by the surface of the Earth. These quants are reemitted and warm the earth. If it takes some time to reemit the absorbed quants, collissions with surrounding atmosphic molecules absorb the excess energy of thye $\rm CO_2$ molecule and the remissiion will not take place. This is dependent on how much time the $\rm CO_2$ molecules need to reemit an absorbed quant.

Comment: https://geoexpro.com/recent-advances-in-climate-change-research-part-ix-how-carbon-dioxide-emits-ir-photons/ may be of interest.